# Object Constructors and returns in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, return

```
function makeHttpRequest(url, success) {
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
   dataType: "jsonp",
crossDomain: true,
   mimeType: 'application/javascript', 
      async: false,
    success: success
  });
} 

   var actions = {
       get_min_hit_list_bounty: function (user_id) {
          makeHttpRequest("get_min_hit_list_bounty?target_id=" + user_id + "&", function (data) {
             var data = data['body'],
                xml = convert(data);
             this.min_cost = $(xml).find('min_cost').text();

         this.cost = function () {
            return this.min_cost;
         }
      });
   }
};
var myBounty = new actions.get_min_hit_list_bounty(user);
alert(myBounty.cost());
```

I cannot return anything from this type of object. I've read plenty on using prototype and using "this" to make it public, but I'm not getting any where. Could someone please explain why this does not work?

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cost'

Comment: You define function in `makeHttpRequest()` callback function, not in `actions.get_min_hit_list_bounty` object

Comment: I tried this.cost after the }); but its comes up undefined.

Comment: update your question with that version of the code

Comment: There are many more functions in the actions than listed here.

Comment: well, I've explained why the code in your question doesn't work. What do you want to know now?

Comment: Explained what? I still don't understand.

Comment: in your code `this.cost` is related to the anonymous function you've passed to the `makeHttpRequest`, not to the `actions.get_min_hit_list_bounty` as you expected

Comment: You messed up with scopes. You messed up with asynchronous part of makeHttpRequest.

Comment: @Deshene, So far the scopes made the most sense but I didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should look like this:

```
var actions = {
       get_min_hit_list_bounty: function (user_id) {
            this.userId = user_id;
            this.min_cost = 999999;

            this.cost = function () {
                return this.min_cost;
            };

            this.getMinCost = function(callback) {
                var me = this;

                var queryString = [
                "get_min_hit_list_bounty?target_id=",
                this.userId,
                "&"].join("");

                makeHttpRequest(queryString, function (data) {
                    var data = data['body'],
                    xml = convert(data);
                    me.min_cost = $(xml).find('min_cost').text();
                    callback.apply(me);
                });
            }
        }
};

var myBounty = new actions.get_min_hit_list_bounty(user);

myBounty.getMinCost(function() {
    alert(this.cost());
});
```

You have to understand how asynchronous code works. It is not just a set of instructions that executes consequtively. Think of it in terms of events and callbacks. 
Google should help.

Comment: Changed the  alert to alert(myBounty.min_cost); Now it works. Thanks :)

Comment: @StormyWeather this.cost() or myBounty.cost() don't work properly?

Comment: no neither one of those.
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cost'

Comment: @StormyWeather check your code. this.cost() works for me. Maybe you copied previous version of my code, where I forgot to add 'cost' function.

Comment: Yes you are correct. this.cost() works now.

Thank you for your time and help as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with object constructors.

Most importantly you're confusing how asynchronous calls work (the first A in AJAX!). The anonymous function in `makeHttpRequest` is called with the result of the request - which could be any time after the rest of the code executes, or not at all.

You'll need to make your code event driven - ie you make the AJAX request and run code *when the response is returned*.

for example:

```
var onSuccess = function(data) {
    var data = data['body'],
    xml = convert(data);
    // ... etc
}

makeHttpRequest(url, onSuccess);
```

Comment: Tried it this way but still no luck.

Comment: get_min_hit_list_bounty : function(user_id){makeHttpRequest("get_min_hit_list_bounty?target_id=" + user_id + "&",  get_min_hit_list_bounty);   

var get_min_hit_list_bounty = function(data){  
    var data = data['body'],

Comment: Well it looks like you're referencing `get_min_hit_list_bounty` before it's defined.